# Composition function equal identity and differentiability

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Let $f : (0, \infty) \to (0, \infty)$ be a differentiable function such that $f \circ f = id$, but $f \neq id$ (here,
$id$ denotes the identity function). Show that there exists $c \in (0, \infty)$ such that $f'(c) = −1$.

I used the Chain Rule to derive  the equation $f \circ f = id$, but I couldn't get any further.
I was in doubt if I should somehow use the Mean Value Theorem, because this theorem is enunciated in books for bounded intervals of the type (a, b), and in this exercise we have an unbounded interval.

Answer (score 2):

Take some $x$ such that $f(x) \neq x$. By the mean value theorem, there exists some $c$ between $x$ and $f(x)$ such that $f’(c) = \frac{f(x) - f(f(x))}{x - f(x)} = -1$.